# Wrong video drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC.
I have problem with video card. In settings 'Additional drivers' there are two options of video card. Both varians are wrong.

- NVIVIDA binary driver - version 384.90 from nvidia-384 (non open, tested)
- X.Org X server - Nouevau display driver x server xorg-video-nouveau (open source)

When I use first, it works OK, but big problem is with my screen. Sometimes (after 20 minutes or 1 hour) screen is stuck.

When I use second one, screen is OK, but I can't play film with VLC because I don't see images of film but I heart audio. Or It's not working second monitor. Its behavior is strange.
Can you hlep me please, I don't know, how I to repair that.

My computer info:

### **BaseInfo**:

- Motherboard: AsRock P55
- Processor:    4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU 760 @ 2.80GHz
- Memory: 12GB
- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

### **Display**:

- Resolution    1680x1050 pixels
- OpenGL Renderer   Unknown
- X11 Vendor    The X.Org Foundation

### **SCSI Disks**:

- ATA Hitachi HDS72101
- ATA Samsung SSD 850

Thank you for your help.